# Не удаётся подключить слот к кнопке в QT(no such slot)

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qmake, qt6

у меня есть код:

**testbutton.h**

```cpp
#include <QMainWindow>
class testbutton : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    testbutton();

    QCheckBox *test_btn;

public slots:
    void on_btn_clicked(bool clicked);
};
```

**testbutton.cpp**

```
#include "testbutton.h"

testbutton::testbutton()
{
    test_btn = new QCheckBox(this);
    connect(test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(on_btn_clicked(bool clicked)));

}
void testbutton::on_btn_clicked(bool clicked)
{
    if(clicked == true){
        qDebug("CHECKED");
    }
    else{
        qDebug("UNCHECKED");
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    testbutton b;
    b.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

здесь я просто в качестве теста пытаюсь привязать функцию к виджету, но мне выдаёт: *qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such slot testbutton::on_btn_clicked(bool clicked) in ..\test\testbutton.cpp:6*
я просмотрел подобные моему вопросы, но решения, предложенные там(проверить moc файл, перезапустить qmake, добавить Q_OBJECT), мне не помогли. Возможно, в меру своих знаний и невнимательности, я упускаю что-то. Прошу помочь.

Comment: используйте новый синтаксис connect (без SIGNAL, SLOT) и тогда компилятор будет ругаться на ошибки

Comment: можете пожалуйста уточнить, что за синтаксис

Comment: @WhyCoding
https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял в чём была ошибка, в функции **connect** в параметрах функции-слота вместо **bool clicked** необходимо написать просто **bool**. Таким образом получится:

```cpp
connect(test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(on_btn_clicked(bool)));
```

Comment: Удваиваю совет Павла использовать "новый" (ему больше 10 лет так-то) синтаксис коннекта

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    SLOT(switcherIconChange_clicked(bool menuPosition)

это у тебя в слоте

единственный переопределенный слот у тебя с таким именем)))))))

```
public slots:
    void on_btn_clicked(bool clicked);
```

напиши вот это

```
connect(test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(on_btn_clicked(bool clicked)));
```

и измени в .cpp имя функции на `void on_btn_clicked(bool clicked)`

Comment: Только тип аргумента, без имени переменной (clicked). `SLOT(on_btn_clicked (bool))`

Comment: да, я допустил ошибку при составлении вопроса, я исправил всё так же, как у вас, но ошибка осталась

Comment: Ну скидывай, то что написал

Comment: (https://imgur.com/1gEox11)

Comment: @why, не знаю у меня все нормально, сейчас перезапустил никаких уведомлений 
Qt 7.0.2, собираюсь на 5.15.2, c++17, qmake, mingw